# Serial port does not receive data

Tags: c#, serial-port

first of all sorry for my english :)

I have a PCI serial ports card with 2 COM ports. I am using it to receive data from another computer via serial cables. (That other computer will be named as "**Sender**" subsequently)

The problem is, when cables are plugged in to my computer and i reboot (Windows 7),(Sender is still running...), then my PC does not receive any data. But when i reboot and after that I connect the cables in my PC it starts to receive. I temporary solved it by firstly starting my PC and then the Sender PC, but it's really a terrible solution...

I tried to connect my PC with a different computer (different sender), and it works good.
So I think that the problem can be with my main Sender. Maybe it is waiting for some signal from my computer that the ports are ready? Or Windows 7 can block my serial ports card (standard COM1 which is not on that card works fine) during reboot? Maybe I have to manually send some signal to Sender that I'm ready? By the way, I cannot, in any way, make adjustments to the Sender PC; only turn it on or off.

I do not have any expertise on serial ports so I really don't know what to do, or what I'm currently doing wrong.

Any ideas? (my receiver application is programmed in C#)

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention that when the cables are connected... reboot... then ports can't be even opened.

Comment: Perhaps the "sender PC" crashed when it has nowhere to send the data?

Comment: No, sender is still running... when i unplug, reboot and then plug in, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in card... I changed for new one and now its working correctly. Looks like the card was too old for Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem caused by the handshake signals.  The Sender's DSR (Data Set Ready) is wired to your DTR (Data Terminal Ready).  It will see the signal turn off when you reboot, now it gets sulky about sending anything because it thinks that you are no longer connected.  You can exacerbate this problem by not setting the SerialPort.DtrEnable to *true* in your program, that's very commonly overlooked.

Same story with the RTS and CTS signals, if you set the SerialPort.Handshake property to anything else than Handshake.RequestToSend (the recommended value) then it now becomes your job to control the signal.  You must set the RtsEnable property to *true* explicitly in your code.

It tends to work by accident, you're apt to use another program to test the connection.  Like HyperTerminal or Putty, they'll turn the signals on for you and your program will now operate correctly.

This kind of bug could of course also exist in Sender.  If you can't fix that code then all you can do is rewire the cable.  Connect RTS to DSR and CTS on the Sender side to it will always see the signals turned on.

Comment: Thanks for answer and nice explanation, I will try it next week and let you know how it went.

Comment: It did not help... but I forgot to mention that when the cables are connected... reboot... ports can't be even opened.